# How can I order by the newest record from more 1 one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 activity for an item. View, Like and Comment. I want to get a list of items according to the latest activity and which activity is done in each item.

I tried to assign a single alias name for mulitple field and use it with order by... But it fails...

How can i achieve this?

```
SELECT item_name, item_view_date AS date, item_like_date AS date, item_comment_date AS date
FROM item 
LEFT JOIN item_like ON like_item_id = item_id 
LEFT JOIN item_comment ON comment_item_id = item_id 
LEFT JOIN item_view ON view_item_id = item_id 
GROUP BY item_id 
ORDER BY date
```

Comment: Have a look at how some more successful questions are presented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MySQL [`GREATEST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function that returns the greatest out of the elements provided :

```
SELECT item_name, MAX(item_view_date) AS date1, MAX(item_like_date) AS date2, MAX(item_comment_date) AS date3
FROM item 
LEFT JOIN item_like ON like_item_id = item_id 
LEFT JOIN item_comment ON comment_item_id = item_id 
LEFT JOIN item_view ON view_item_id = item_id 
GROUP BY item_name
ORDER BY GREATEST(COALESCE(date1,date2,date3),
                  COALESCE(date2,date1,date3),
                  COALESCE(date3,date1,date2))
```

As you can see, I've add `MAX(date)` on each of the dates, because you are left joining and using a `GROUP BY` clause without specifiyng an aggregation function. Each column usually must be either specified on the group by clause, or with an aggregation function.

Then there is the `COALESCE()` part, because you are `LEFT` joining, there can be `NULL` values , therefore - use `COALESCE()` to eliminate the null values .

Comment: Yes, didn't look at the logic of the query, assumed its correct. Fixed @Strawberry

Comment: @Dino Updated , see if you understand